# wget connection stuck - log file location?

Tags: wget, ipv6, mint, ipv4

A client of mine could not download anything via WGET from any website. He didn't get any error messages in the terminal. The connection simply remained in the "connecting" status. It did DNS IPV4 & IPV6 resolving and then remained in "connecting" status.

**Linux OS:** Linux Mint (I have encountered this issue in the past with RedHat Enterprise too).

1. I checked the Iptables rules, then disabled the Firewall completely to eliminate any suspicion (UFW) + flush all Iptables rules.
2. Checked DNS (port 53) - all were set correctly. To eliminate the possibility of ISP blocking of WGET I set Google DNS: 8.8.8.8 & 8.8.4.4 - for IPV4 and 2001:4860:4860::8888 & 2001:4860:4860::8844 - for IPV6.
3. I checked the validity of the certificate and all were correct.
   However the connection remained stuck in the "connecting" status, without any error in the terminal.

After I declared for all users IPV4 ON and IPV6 OFF for WGET, all started working instantly without any problem. WGET connects instantly!

```
sudo nano /etc/wgetrc
#Force IPV4 only
inet4_only = on

#Force IPV6 OFF
inet6_only = off
```

**The question is:** Where is the location of the WGET log?
I'm curious to see what the Log specifies, and what reason it gives for IPV6 connection refused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Log file

The WGET log file is specified by the `-o` parameter:

```
wget -r --tries=10 http://any.domain.xy/ -o log
```

You can set it up as you need.

### Connection diagnosis

Test whether TCP port 443 (or 80 or any other you wish) is available on the remote side. Use `netcat` or `nc` tool:

#### IPv4 test

```
nc -4zv www.seznam.cz 443
```

#### IPv6 test

```
nc -6zv www.seznam.cz 443
```

Correct response with available TCP port is:

```
Connection to www.seznam.cz 443 port [tcp/https] succeeded!
```

Comment: Awesome @netbat! Thank you.